# How to open another app from my app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried to open that app `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cb-pay/id1333054033?mt=8` from my existing app. Problem is whenever I've tried to open, it always shows

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cb-pay://app" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed.

even I've installed that app in my iPhone and already configured inside `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.

**Is that because of app name is included space or dash between two words? I've tried to open photos app inside my app, it's working.**

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(cpayURL!) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(cpayURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(cpayURL!)
    }
} else if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(cpayInstallURL!) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(cpayInstallURL!)
}
```

Comment: How do you know that that is the URL scheme for that app?

Comment: @Paulw11 I just browse that app from url. Is that correct?

Comment: You mean that if you type `cb-pay://app` into Safari on your device the app opens?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cb-pay/id1333054033?mt=8 like that. and I assume that scheme name is `cb-pay`

Comment: No.  The scheme is registered in the app's Info.plist.  It may not have a URL scheme or it could be something else.  `canOpenURL` is telling you that there is no app installed that responds to `cb-pay://`

Comment: try with `cb-pay://`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik try already. it's not working.

Comment: @Paulw11 so is there anyway to do it?

Comment: is this possible to attach the project

Comment: You need to extract the IPA file from your phone, open it and check what URL scheme the app registers (if any).  Anything else is just guessing.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik why it's needed to attach? Above code is enough to test it.